# How many 7-digit numbers with distinct digits can be made that are divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

How many 7-digit numbers with distinct digits can be made that are divisible by 3?
First of all, I counted all the ways to insert 7 of 10 digits in a number making the number divisible by 3.
Digits that can be left:
a)012, 015, 018, 024, 027, 036, 039, 045, 048, 057, 069, 078   **12 ways** ;
b)123, 126, 129, 135, 138, 147, 156, 159, 168, 189  **10 ways**;
c)234, 237, 246, 249, 258, 267, 279  **7 ways**;
345, 348, 357, 369, 378  **5 ways**;
456, 459, 468, 489 **4 ways**;
567, 579  **2 ways**;
678 **1 way**;
789 **1 way**.

In case a), all the remaining 7 digits are no 0, so I counted: 7! x 12 = 60480 numbers
In all the other cases (30), from 7! I subtracted the cases in which the number begin with 0 (6! cases).
So, 30 x (7! - 6!) = 30 x (5040 - 720) = 4320 x 30 = 129600 numbers.
In total I counted **190080 numbers with distinct digits that are divisible by 3**.
Is this process correct?

This problem is the number 23 of "Guts February 2000 HMMT". It doesn't specify if the leftmost digit is permitted to be 0; I supposed that a number can't begin with a "0". The reason I wrote this problem on this forum is that the answer posted in the "answer sheet " of that competition is 224640. I tried hard, also considering "0" as the leftmost digit, but I hadn't been able to find this number. I wanted to verify with other people if it could be a mistake in the answer sheet.

I thank in advance those who want to solve this problem.

Comment: This looks good (but I didn't verify your arithmetic). You might want to include an explanation of how you determined these digits that are left. $\quad$ You might want to clarify that the "digits that are left" are the 3 that are not chosen. I initially read it as the "leftmost digits of the number", and it took a while to understand how you were approaching it.

Comment: For example, if I don't consider digits (0,1,2), the other 7 (3,4,5,6,7,8,9) give necessarily a number that is multiple of 3.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Your posting should clarify, *up front*, whether the leftmost digit of the 7 digit number is permitted to be $~0.$

Comment: I was surprised to have only 190080, so I did a short script, and I obtain 190080.

Comment: This problem is the number 23 of "Guts February 2000 HMMT". It doesn't specify if the leftmost digit is permitted to be 0; I supposed that a number can't begin with a "0". The reason I wrote this problem on this forum is that the answer posted in the "answer sheet " of that competition is 224640. I tried hard, also considering "0" as the leftmost digit, but I hadn't been able to find this number. I wanted to verify with other people if it could be a mistake in the answer sheet. Thank you!

Comment: You establish 42 ways to pick the numbers; each can be arranged in as many as 7! ways (allowing an initial 0). But 42(7!) = 211680, which is *less* than the answer sheet's claim. I'm not sure where they got that number from.

Comment: Are you sure that the original problem specified that the digits have to be unique?

Comment: Why don't you simply count the $7$-digit numbers with different digits and divide that count by $3$? :-)

Comment: @Dominique - because that doesn't work. There are $120$ ways to pick $7$ distinct digits, of which $42 \ne 120/3$ have sum divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to be correct.

The number of such numbers with $0$ as one of its digits is equal to the number of ways to choose 3 non-zero digits with sum divisible by 3. This is equal to the number of ways where all leave the same remainder mod 3, plus when all 3 are  different mod 3. This is equal to $3+3^3=30$. For each of these, there are $6 \times 6!$ ways.

When $0$ is not one of the digits, we need to count the number of pairs of non-zero digits whose sum is a multiple of 3. This is equal to $3^2 +{3\choose2}=12$, the first term being when they are congruent to 1, 2 mod 3 and the second term being for all numbers to be multiples of 3. For each such set, there are $7!$ ways to arrange the digits.

This gives the answer:
$30\times6\times6!+12\times7!=129600+60480=190080$